# How to determine where an image is stored?

Tags: image

I have an image that is at `http://sharepoint_site_name/images/filename.jpg`

I have searched high and low and I cannot figure out where this image is stored. Can someone point me in the right direction to determine the location please? Thanks!

If it helps at all it is a background image on the home page of a sharepoint 2010 site. Thanks for any help.

Comment: check for the Image library and inside that ur image file.

Comment: you check the image library by navigating to /sitename/images.

Answer (score 4):

Open the site in SharePoint designer. There should be a folder or a document library with "images" as the URL component. Easiest way is to open the All Files folder from the SharePoint Designer which will give you the exact location. Certainly the image is stored in Content DB

Comment: or if the image is added through a Feature in a Farm Solution and still is uncustomized then in a sub folder of the SharePointRoot, but in that case any changes should go through an updated solution or into the Content DB

Answer (score 0):

when you have the url

```
http://mysite/images/myimage.jpg
```

to me that indicates its in the style library within a folder called images ;), so goto the style library and you should see it there!

for more info on style lib:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg447066(v=office.14).aspx

**to goto your style library:**

goto **top level site collection** -> click **site actions** -> click **view all site content** -> **under Document Libraries**  you should see **style library**.

or

```
http://mysitecol/Style%20Library/Forms/AllItems.aspx
```

if it was stored on the file system in images it would show under /_layouts/images but its not so thats why you only see /images which is under style library folder!